# What would make these store display Star Wars sets particularly valuable?

Tags: star-wars, value

I came across this display a trade show/swap meet. Now almost all the other toys/collectibles/etc. had a price tag on them (some were even in excess of $1,000).

However these Star Wars sets had a note that read:

> LEGO Store Display. One of the few remaining. NEED to sell, make reasonable offer to take home with you.

What would makes these sets valuable? Are they rare as the note claims? Are they valuable because they were a display a LEGO Store? Something else entirely?

I am not asking what a "reasonable" offer is, as that is subjective; rather is there something objectively intrinsic to the value of them?

Sets in question are:

1. 8036: Separatists Shuttle
2. 7754: Home One Mon Calamari Star Cruiser
3. 8039: Venerator Class Republic Attack Cruiser

[image: star wars lego display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These displays are indeed rare, because LEGO demands that retailers destroy them after use, and most of them oblige. The sets inside are unfortunately glued together, so they don't have much value. They are valuable to collectors of displays, but that is a fairly limited audience.